# sending HTML form data to python Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a form in one my html files, the code for which is:

```
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Mechanical Turk ID: <input type="text" name="turkID">
</form>
```

and my python looks like :

```
@app.route("/upload", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def upload():
    img = request.files['webcam']
    try:
        text = request.form["turkID"]
    except Exception as inst:
       print type(inst)     # the exception instance
       print inst.args      # arguments stored in .args
       print inst      
    filename = secure_filename(img.filename)
    img.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    return "good"
```

it keeps failing the try part and the output of the exception is:

```
 <class 'werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError'>
('turkID',)
400: Bad Request
```

I've tried request.form, request.POST.get, request.POST, and cgi, but none are working.

Comment: Your form and your code are not agreeing - your form is pointed at `demo_form.asp` and has no `webcam` input of type `file`, while your Python code is mounted at `/upload` and is grabbing a file named 'webcam'.  Can you make sure that your HTML code is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not compatible with the Python code you have provided. You may want to replace `demo_form.asp` in the action with `/upload/`. You are also not sending any file to the field `webcam`.